# The same order type groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, open-problem

Let $G$ be a finite group and $n$ be a natural number. Set $T(G)=\{g\in G|$ $%
g^{n}=1\}$ and $L_{n}(G)=|T(G)|$. Two finite groups $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are
called of the same order type if and only if $L_{n}(G_{1})=L_{n}(G_{2})$ for
all $n$.

If $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are the same order type, then we have  1) $%
|G_{1}|=|G_{2}|$ 2) The set of all element orders of $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are
equal.

It is well-known when $G_{1}$ is a non-abelian simple group $G_{2}$ is too.

In 1987, J. G. Thompson put forward the following problem.

Thompson's Problem. Suppose that $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are two finite
groups of the same order type. If $G_{1}$ is solvable, is it true that $G_{2}
$ is also necessarily solvable?

Rulin Shen in the paper: On same order type groups, SA"{U}. Fen Bilimleri
Dergisi, 15. Cilt, 2. Say\i, s.156-158, 2011, proved that Thompson's problem is true for nilpotent and
supersolvable groups. Also, he proved that problem is true for solvable
groups with more than one connected prime graph component (please see Shen
R, Shi W. On Thompson problem (in Chinese). Sci Sin Math, 2010, 40(6):
533-537).

Now this problem remains only for the case where the prime graph is
connected. Has there ever been proof of this residual state? If not, I
would appreciate it if you have an idea to prove it, and share it.

Comment: $T(G)$ is not the set of orders. An element $g$ with $g^n=1$ need not have order $n$. [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.10653) "same-order-type" is defined differently, for example. Can you give a link to the definition, which you are using?

Comment: The paper by [Shen](https://www-tandfonline-com.uaccess.univie.ac.at/doi/full/10.1080/00927872.2011.574663) defines $g\sim h$ iff $g$ and $h$ have the same *order*. And "The set of sizes of the equivalence classes with respect to this relation is called the same-order type of $G$."

Comment: This is a difficult problem, which has been open for a long time. If someone had a proof, I am sure it would have been published.